# Openshift - What does this command mean? oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt

Tags: java, jsf, cloud, openshift

What does this command mean?

```
oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt
```

And why the results vary so much?!
from 35000 to 80000 after some time

The interesting moment that there is no relationship between application speed and that number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the KB on the OpenShift website, that is how many times your application has hit the gears memory limit (which is 512MB for small gears).  This may or may not result in  your application restarting, depending on what caused it.  If that number keeps increasing, that usually means that you either:
a.)  have a memory leak in your application that you should find.
b.)  should upgrade to a larger gear size because you are running a large application

Keep in mind that anything that runs on your gear uses the memory, including the database, cron scripts, etc.  Especially if you are using java & a database cartridge on one gear, you can run into memory issues pretty quickly.  It is suggested that you try using a scaled application so that the database can be on it's own gear, or try using a larger gear size (or even a scaled larger gear).

https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1082-how-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful tips. Is there a possibility to mount a database on some external free resource?  And connect to it from openshift app?

Comment: Yes! You could use any DBaaS solution that you would like and it should work with OpenShift Online.  Something like MongoLab, etc